# Speed problems with SetValue, ToType and Reflection

Tags: c#, performance, reflection

I have a 'speed problem' with a program im currently developing. I already have encountered the methods which costs some time.

```
public void ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()
    {
        List<byte[]> items = new List<byte[]>() { new byte[2], new byte[2], new byte[2], new byte[2] };

        items[0][0] = this.DataBytes[0];
        items[0][1] = this.DataBytes[1];
        items[1][0] = this.DataBytes[2];
        items[1][1] = this.DataBytes[3];
        items[2][0] = this.DataBytes[4];
        items[2][1] = this.DataBytes[5];
        items[3][0] = this.DataBytes[6];
        items[3][1] = this.DataBytes[7];

        int i = 0;
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> result = this.determineCanMessageValueFields();

        foreach (var prop in result)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageStatusValueField))
            {
                prop.SetValue(this, new MessageStatusValueField(BitConverter.ToUInt16(items[i], 0), prop.Name, this.UnitType), null);
            }
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageValueField))
            {
                prop.SetValue(this, new MessageValueField(BitConverter.ToUInt16(items[i], 0), prop.Name), null);
            }
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageValueFieldInt32))
            {
                prop.SetValue(this, new MessageValueFieldInt32(BitConverter.ToUInt16(items[i], 0), prop.Name), null);
            }
            else if (prop.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(false).Count(x => x.GetType() == typeof(BitmaskValueFieldClass)) > 0)
            {
                var tempField = new MessageValueField(BitConverter.ToUInt16(items[i], 0), prop.Name);
                prop.SetValue(this, Convert.ChangeType(tempField, prop.PropertyType), null);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }




     private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> determineCanMessageValueFields()
            {
                //Get all properties with the 
                //custom attribute [IsValueField]
                return this.GetType().GetProperties()
                                     .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                     .Count(x => x.GetType() == typeof(IsValueField)) > 0)
                                     .OrderBy(x => ((IsValueField)x.GetCustomAttributes(false)[0]).ValueFieldIndex);
            }

 public object ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            //...only convert if the conversion type is a BitmaskValueFieldClass
            if (conversionType.GetCustomAttributes(false).Count(x => x.GetType() == typeof(BitmaskValueFieldClass)) == 0)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("The conversion is only available for conversion types with the BitmaskValueFieldClass attribute");
            }

            //...create an instance of the conversion type
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(conversionType);

            //...go thru each property and set the value
            foreach (var item in instance.GetType().BaseType.GetProperties())
            {
                item.SetValue(instance, this.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(this, null), null);
            }

            return instance;
        }
```

The method `ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()` is the sticking point. I know it is because of the `prop.SetValue()` and the `ToType() IConvertible` method calls. When i am removing the `ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()` method i gain the missing time i need to fulfill the project.

Is there a way to improve the whole thing? Problem is that the idea has to be as it is. In the `ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()` method i have to map the returning DataFrame, the DataBytes array, to the MessageValueField properties of the specific class. Im getting all containing messagevaluefields by calling the `ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()`.

**Edit #1**

Some further Info:
The `ConvertDataFrameToValueFields` Method is called several times in the program life cycle. I have an object which contains at first the DataBytes array. Now i have to map the values of the DataBytes array to the specific four properties. `this` in the `ConvertDataFrameToValueFields` method **points not always the same type of class!** It can be type of ClassA or ClassB or ClassC. ClassA, ClassB and ClassC have different properties with the custom attribute `IsValueField`. Thats why i call `determineCanMessageValueFields`. I need to get the four specific properties, get the type of the property, and set the value based on the property type. I do this several times in the program life cycle and this is not always the same type. I hope this makes it a little bit clearer.

In Short:

DataBytes array has been filled --> Get the message value fields of the current object the DataBytes have been filled --> Determine the type of the specific property --> Set the value with the specific DataByte value(s)

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027980/improving-performance-reflection-what-alternatives-should-i-consider)

Comment: The `NotImplementedException` is misleading. `ToType` should throw a `NotSupportedException` for a `typeof(BitmaskValueFieldClass)`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but changing the type of exception does not lead to a performance upgrade.

Comment: What happens, when `result.size() > 4`? Your code probably would break with an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Could you put the whole class for review? It would be great to see the properties you have in order to understand better. Because right now I have a hard time understanding why your class would use reflection on itself.

Answer (score 2):

first of all reflection is expensive when used often. What you can do is

- cache the properties to set

  ```
  Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>> _propertiesCache
  ```
- remove the copying over by creating the result immediatly and let it parse it itself

  ```
  public TMessage ConvertDataFrameToValueFields<TMessage>(byte[] dataBytes, Whatever unitType) where TMessage : new()
  {
      var result = new TMessage();

      ...
      // use the constructor which takes a ushort and the propertyName. The class itself has to know how to interpret the ushort
      fieldValue = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType, value, prop.Name);
     ...
  }
  ```
- limit the calls to GetCustomAttributes by using the result twice

  ```
  var isValueField = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<IsValueFieldAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
  if (isValueField != null)
      results.Add(isValueField.FieldIndex, prop);
  ```
- remove the conversion of byte[] to List because it is not needed. Convert takes the startindex anyway
- remove the need to store the bytes in the class

and together it will be

```
class ByteConverter
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>> _propertiesCache = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>>();

    public TMessage ConvertDataFrameToValueFields<TMessage>(byte[] dataBytes, Whatever unitType) where TMessage : new()
    {
        var result = new TMessage();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var prop in GetMessageValueFields<TMessage>())
        {
            var value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(dataBytes, i);
            object fieldValue = null;
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageStatusValueField))
            {
                fieldValue = new MessageStatusValueField(value, prop.Name, this.UnitType);
            }
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageValueField))
            {
                fieldValue = new MessageValueField(value, prop.Name);
            }
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageValueFieldInt32))
            {
                fieldValue = new MessageValueFieldInt32(value, prop.Name);
            }
            else if (prop.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BitmaskValueFieldClass)))
            {
                // use the constructor which takes a ushort and the propertyName. The class itself has to know how to interpret the ushort
                fieldValue = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType, value, prop.Name);
            }

            if (fieldValue != null)
                prop.SetValue(result, fieldValue, null);

            i += 2;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetMessageValueFields<TMessage>()
    {
        var type = typeof(TMessage);
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties;
        if (!_propertiesCache.TryGetValue(type, out properties))
        {
            //Get all properties with the 
            //custom attribute [IsValueField]
            var results = new SortedList<int, PropertyInfo>();
            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
            {
                var isValueField = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<IsValueFieldAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (isValueField != null)
                    results.Add(isValueField.FieldIndex, prop);

            }
            properties = results.Values;
            _propertiesCache.Add(type, properties);
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

remember to hold one global instance of this class or make everything static

you have not many Message classes and convert a lot you can also create Delegates to set the properties.

create to cache it

```
var message = Expression.Parameter(messageType, "message");
var value = Expression.Parameter(prop.PropertyType, "value");
var body = Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(message, prop), value);
var setProperty = Expression.Lambda(body, message, value).Compile();
```

and use it

```
setProperty.DynamicInvoke(message, fieldValue);
```